# Forcing await to return a value in dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I know this is such a 101 question but it totally goes against my intuition so I need to ask about it.

Say I make a method:

```
String read(String key) => return storage.read(key);
```

Now that's not going to work because `storage.read` is an asynchronous function. No problem:

```
String read(String key) => return await storage.read(key);
```

Now here, I would think that means, wait for this `Future` to complete then return the resulting `String`. But that's not ok, because as soon as I use await I need to make my function `async` too.

```
String read(String key) async => return await storage.read(key);
```

Ok, But that doens't work because an `async` function, apparently by definition, returns a `Future` (or `void`).

```
Future<String> read(String key) async => return await storage.read(key);
```

And there we go. This function is valid.

So, if I'm using a `async` function somewhere in my call stack, everything above it has to be an `async` function, and return a `Future`, yes?

The reason this goes against my intuition is because I think, why not allow me the control to say, "when you get to this function, (in the call stack) resolve the future into it's actual value and return the value." That seems unallowed. Instead we must pass up the option to the caller to resolve the future themselves.

Am I missing something here?

Now, I don't think I've ever used them but I've heard of `Completer`s. Is the point of a `Completer` to allow you to explicitly resolve the `Future` such that a value can be returned rather than a `Future<value>`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force async code to magically be sync. You need to accommodate this all the way up the return tree. That's what things like `FutureBuilder` do for you: provide a widget tree to show while the real data is in transit.

Comment: thank you, yes, it's clear to me that the way I think it should work isn't the way it works. My question is WHY do those limitations exist? Why do I need to accommodate the asynchronous nature all the way up the return tree? C is async, so A calls B and B calls C. A says, "I need some data, B," B says, "I need some data, C," C says, "here's a promise to get you that data," Why can't B `await` the promise, simply running, blocking execution until this promise completes, then when it does, return to A and say, "here's the data you asked for." I don't see where the language limitation comes from.

Comment: could it be that I'm thinking of these as threads? that async spins of a different thread that processes in parallel, when in reality, that's not what's going on at all?

Comment: The main thing to consider is that build() is being called 60 times a second and has 1/60th of a second to deliver an entire new widget tree for the frame.  You can't "wait" in the middle of that.  Calls being made from build() must return in a timely manner.  So in your example, "B" can't wait.  B has 16 ms to yield an answer, even if it's just "I promise to give you an answer sometime... try me again later".

Comment: That is good to know, but I think I should mention that I never said anything about flutter. I've only been talking about the rules inherent to the dart language itself. and it's still unclear to me where this limitation comes from.

Comment: This article has a good explanation about why async "infects" the call stack: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/